# UIAlertView wont call function

Tags: objective-c, ios, uialertview

I have a function that lets you choose how to take a picture (from gallery or from camera). If there is no "content" (you havent already taken a picture) then you are free to do it. If it does have content (you have already taken a photo) then it pops up a dialogue box asking if you are sure. I have implemented the UIAlertViewDelegate so that I can tell which button they press.

My problem comes when they press OK (button index 0) but the function does not work (it does get called, i stepped through it with the debugger). It also does not let me pop up another dialogue box if I press the button again.

I'm stumped as to what the problem is, and I can't think of what to Google to try and find out.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
-(IBAction)galleryButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (!mHasContent)
    {
        [mDelegate performSelector:@selector(galleryButtonPressed:) withObject:self];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView* warning = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Section Complete" message:@"You have already taken an image. Selecting another will overwrite it, you can select to take another image above. Are you sure you wish to continue?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: @"Cancel", nil];

        [warning setTag:GALLERY];
        [warning show];
        [warning release];
    }
}

-(IBAction)cameraButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (!mHasContent)
    {
        [mDelegate performSelector:@selector(captureImageButtonPressed:) withObject:self];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView* warning = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Section Complete" message:@"You have already taken an image. Selecting another will overwrite it, you can select to take another image above. Are you sure you wish to continue?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: @"OK", @"Cancel", nil];

        [warning setTag:CAMERA];
        [warning show];
        [warning release];
    }
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // If they selected OK then resend the event to take a photo or select from the gallery
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        mHasContent = NO;

        if ([alertView tag] == GALLERY)
        {
            [self galleryButtonPressed:mGalleryButton];
        }
        else
        {
            [self cameraButtonPressed:mCameraButton];
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried this with onClick and willDismiss.... and none of those worked either.

Answer (score 4):

Try this method...

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex { 
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        mHasContent = NO;

        if ([alertView tag] == GALLERY)
        {
            [self galleryButtonPressed:mGalleryButton];
        }
        else
        {
            [self cameraButtonPressed:mCameraButton];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the value in "Gallary"  & "CAMERA" ? is it int or string

Comment: It is: 
#define GALLERY 1
#define CAMERA 0

Comment: Do one thing.. get the value of alertview.tag in local int temp = alertview.tag  and compare that value with CAMERA/GALLERY

Comment: I tried it with not changing anything in there, so had it doing the if statements and commented the function calls and setting mHasContent to NO and it worked like you would expect it to. So it would pop up, I could press OK and then press it and it would pop up again.

Comment: is that the way you wanted to do?

Comment: No, I want it to do some stuff in there. I got rid of all functionality which is not helpful. I'm trying to find out why it wont work if I do anything in there - or a way around it.

Comment: Ok, if you could post it as a new reply rather than a comment that would be good, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

implement this delegate method

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView*)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have said. I've already tried it with that and also "willDissWithButtonIndex" and non of them worked either.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two buttons.. Use actionsheet.

-(IBAction) takePic:(id) sender
{

```
GroceryApplicationAppDelegate *appDelegate = (GroceryApplicationAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo",@"Choose Existing Photo",nil];
[sheet setDelegate:self];
[sheet showInView:appDelegate.window];
[sheet release];
}
```

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

```
if(buttonIndex == 0)
{

    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"No Camera Found" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        return;
    }

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

if (buttonIndex == 1) 
{

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

}

Comment: You can modify this code and use it according to your project.